# d3js - calculate distance between two data point in line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am newbie to d3.js. I have unevenly distributed data points on the line graph, when I add new point at right side, I want to remove last data point at left side, as shown in [mike's path transition tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/). I am referring last transition with axes.

So while giving transition, I want to calculate the distance between last two data points, since they are on uneven distance. The total difference between last two points I will apply as effective transition.

Example line graph.
xAxes range: time
[image: graph]

Here point 1st and 2nd have much more distance then other points.
So, while removing 1st element, I need to transit it more.
For 2nd point onwards, I need to transit very small distance.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

```
    var checkList=getCheckedList();     //getting list of parameters:here read1,read2,read3
    updateAxes(checkList,data);
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
    t.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    t.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    var keys=KeyArray;
    var line1;
    for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
    {
        if(actualKeys.indexOf(keys[i]) > -1){

            line1=d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("linear")
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d[keys[i]]); });

            var id="#"+keys[i]+"_line";
            d3.select(id).attr("d",line1(data));  //I want trasition here
        }
    }
```

Added [JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/zqgqE/1/). Its working fine on my local machine, but jsfiddle have some problem. When you click on button, it should transit from right to left as it changes first 5 data points with new 5 data points.

Please notify if anything is not understandable.

Comment: This is just the difference between the first (to be removed) and the second point passed through the x scale, no?

Comment: I think, the original distance shown in graph, will be different as per our graph's total height and width. So we need to get the distance as per graph's relative distance. Basically, I cant write `.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")");`. So I am confused about getting translate equation or my d3js knowledge is not enough.

Comment: The difference between the position of the first and second data points on the graph will give you exactly that.

Comment: In the tutorial you mentioned above, the line: .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ")") moves the path 'one' unit to the left. In your example, the change is, as Lars mentioned, is the difference between the x value of the first and second data point or something like: .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d[0].x - d1[1].x) + ")") (of course there are better ways of getting the first and second elements but I used array index for the sake of simplicity.)

Comment: @sepans I tried your solution, it returns NaN. So transition is not taking place.

Comment: @saumya-suhagiya my solution is very peudocode-ish. No wonder it returns NaN. If you have a jsfiddle or something I can take a look...

Comment: I have added jsFiddle, on my local machine, same code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the x-axis is time, I think the expected UX is to smoothly scroll the graph based on current time or the new point. Removing the first point is a secondary issue. Without knowing more about your goals, I'm skeptical that the UX translation should be based on the first point being removed.

The translation is:

```
var translateX = scale(lastDomainMax) - scale( newDomainMax)
```

You have to clip the chart so the new point scrolls onto the screen. The left side of the chart is clipped as well. The first point will translate off, but the line segment between point 1 and 2 should remain until point 2 scrolls off the chart. From that, you should always keep one point to the left of the chart.

Alternatively, you could change the x-domain to reflect the min/max of the current points in the array. In that case, points 2 through 7 would *expand* horizontally to fill the chart when you remove point 1.

You can see how [d3-traits](https://github.com/gec/d3-traits) does it with its [line chart](https://github.com/gec/d3-traits/blob/master/src/chart/line.js) in the `chartLine.update( 'trend')` method. d3-traits calls what you're doing "trending".